# Rails Controller Tests for Captcha using Shoulda, Factory Girl, Mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, captcha, factory-bot, mocha.js, shoulda

Can someone provide a strategy/code samples/pointers to test Captcha validations + Authlogic using Shoulda, Factory Girl and Mocha?

For instance, my UsersController is something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
validates_captcha

...
def create
...
if captcha_validated?
      # code to deal with user attributes
end
...
end
```

In this case, how do you mock/stub using Shoulda / Factory Girl / Mocha to test valid and invalid responses to the Captcha image?

Appreciate your help,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends where `captcha_validated?` is defined, but you want to mock its return value and then write tests for each case. Something like this:

```
describe UsersController, "POST create" do
  context "valid captcha" do
    before do
      SomeCaptchaObject.expects(:captcha_validated?).returns(true)
    end
    # ...
  end
  context "invalid captcha" do
    before do
      SomeCaptchaObject.expects(:captcha_validated?).returns(false)
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks rspeicher, the "captcha_validated?" is part of the Captcha plugin and is defined as below:

module ValidatesCaptcha
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  
  module ClassMethods
    def validates_captcha
      helper CaptchaHelper
      include ValidatesCaptcha::InstanceMethods
    end
  end
  
  module InstanceMethods
    def captcha_validated?
       CaptchaUtil::encrypt_string(params[:captcha].to_s.gsub(' ', '').downcase) == params[:captcha_validation]
    end    
  end  
end  

I will try your suggestion and report back.

Thanks again - Siva

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve with this setup:

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  context "create action" do

    context "valid user with valid captcha" do

      setup do
        User.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(true)
        @controller.stubs(:captcha_validated?).returns(true)

        post :create, :user => Factory.attributes_for(:user, :captcha => "blahblah")
      end

      should_redirect_to("user home") { user_path(@user) }
    end

    context "valid user with invalid captcha" do
      setup do

        User.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(true)
        @controller.stubs(:captcha_validated?).returns(false)

        post :create, :user => Factory.attributes_for(:user, :captcha => "blahblah")
      end

      should_render_template :new

    end
  end
end
```

Thanks.